# Failed to load Tomcat Server 7 configuration in Eclipse EE Juno

Tags: java, runtime, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

My old server hand an error saying it could not be launch, so I decided to clean everything and reinstall it. upon setting up a new Server this shows up.

[image]

How would I resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you check your tomcat installation directory? Does it contain the aforementioned "web.xml" in "conf" folder?

Comment: I already fixed it by downloading the latest apache tomcat and getting its web.xml inside its conf directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I downloaded the latest tomcat and copied its conf/web.xml to my configuration path in my Eclipse. looks like I was just missing  the web.xml for tomcat itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try Tomcat 7.0.32 in stead. Although I remember using the 27 minor version as well, without any issues. I just used the zip distribution, not an installer.

The error does seem to indicate an incomplete installation, or you're pointing it to the wrong directory.